# How to use blocbuilder in another blocbuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, state, bloc, state-management

I have wrapped the inkwell widget with a BasketBloc and in basket_event i have a function AddProduct which literally adds the add product into the basket and the code for that is as follows:

```dart
onTap: () {
  context
      .read<BasketBloc>()
      ..add(AddProduct(Product.products[index]));
}
```

This piece of code works fine. The thing is that AddProduct is adding a static product from product model into the basket. I want it to add the product from ProductBloc state, e.g instead of Product.products[index] i can do something like state.products[index] and the state being the state of ProductBloc not the BasketBloc. I have tried various things but nothings helps.

Answer (score 2):

okay so i got it to work, i just gave the different bloc different state names and it worked, e.g:

```
BlocBuilder<BasketBloc, BasketState>(
  builder: (context, state) {   //here i changed state to basketstate
```

the other bloc which i had was ProductBloc which was inside the BasketBloc

```
BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
  builder: (context, state) {   //here i changed state to productstate
  ....
context
  .read<BasketBloc>()
  ..add(AddProduct(Product.products[index]));  //here i replaced Product with productstate and it worked
...
```

}